# Pixels and percentages - issues when resizing browser

Tags: html, css, resize, percentage, pixel

any help here would be great.

I'm simply trying to place a header that stretches 100% of the screen. Inside this header is another div containing text. What i have looks fine at full screen, but when i resize down the text stacks on top of each other to accommodate the percentage.

If i set the container width to pixels instead of percentage, the header doesn't stretch the full length of the window unless i specify an exact pixel amount like `1463px` - this doesn't seem right because while it may be appropriate for my laptop/screen dimensions i feel like it wouldn't work on a bigger screen with a maximized window.

I just want everything in my container to be able to be positioned according to the 100% of the browser width and height, but using percentages isn't allowing me to fix the elements so they stay put during resize. I've been working with percentages mostly and am having great difficulty keeping them fixed on resize as opposed to pixel dimensions, basically because using percentages is ensuring that my content is taking up 100% of the browser window, whereas I can't be sure with this when using pixels.

```
   html, body {
       height: 100 % ;
       width: 100 % ;
       padding: 0;
       margin: 0;
   }

   .container {
       width: 100 % ;
       height: 100 % ;
       margin: 0 auto;
   }

   #
   topbar {
       height: 25px;
       background - color: #000000;
    width: 100%;
    }

    # topbartext {
           font - family: times;
           color: #ffffff;
           font - size: 11px;
           text - align: center;
           padding: 5px;
       }
```

The text is what is moving during resize - when I make the window smaller the text just stacks on top of eachother in order to still fit the screen. I don't want it to do this - i just want it to be fixed and not resize.

**HTML :**

```
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="header">
            <div id="topbar">
                <div id="topbartext">$10 SHIPPING TO THE USA FOR ALL ORDERS OVER $150*++ FREE SHIPPING AND RETURNS ON AUSTRALIAN ORDERS OVER $50* ++ *<a href="#">FULL CONDITIONS</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: use css media queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percentages is best for this.

If you want the text to remain in one line you can add the following to your html and css:

html...

```
<div id="topbartext" class="topbartext">
```

css...

```
.topbartext {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Note that:

- In css it is better practice to use a class (`.topbartext`) rather than the id (`#topbartext`).
- Using this method will mean that if you make your page narrower than the text you will have a horizontal scrollbar added (not ideal).  You are probably better off allowing the text to wrap in which case you will need to remove the `height: 25px;`.

Comment: Thanks mate - that helped alot. Another thing - say i set the width of a wrapper to 960px, will this appear the same as it does on my screen in a browser on a larger screen? Like a Mac desktop? Is 960px a safe width for most browsers?

Comment: 960 is no more safe than any other fixed width.  As others have mentioned you should probably be looking at [responsive design](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/) using [media queries](http://cssmediaqueries.com/).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above you could use css media queries. That will take some googling to learn.

If I'm understanding you correctly you can also use a `min-width: 820px` on the body.  This will ensure your body never gets below a certain width it will provide a horizontal scrollbar if it gets smaller than that.

```
html,body {
  min-width: 820px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gYJeL/1/)

[Demo Fiddle Fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/gYJeL/1/show)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to alter the content styles based on parameters like screen size.

[Here's a demo using your example](http://jsfiddle.net/VqQes/) that shrinks the text and allows the #topbar to expand when the screen is smaller than 800px wide (when the text starts to wrap).

For instance:

```
/* Normal styles that apply all the time*/
p    {
    font-size:1em;
}

/* Media query that applies if the display media is a screen
   and the condition between the brackets is met */
@media screen and (max-width:600px)    {
    p    {
         font-size:0.6em;
    }
}
```

You are trying to fit in a lot of text though, you may be better off allowing the surrounding div to expand by removing the fixed height:

#topbar { <strike>height:25px;</strike> };

If you want to fit all your content on a small screen, this is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using JavaScript? I am not sure what you want since you are setting the top bar container to have fixed height which means the text will be out of the container if you do not resize the height. Here is some script to force the width (or height) to full window size (I had trouble with percentage also):

```
function resizeTopBar() {
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;

    var target = document.getElementById("topbar");

    target.style.width = width + "px";
}

window.onresize = function() {
    resizeTopBar();
}
```

The script will not change the way it works (the text will stack on each other) since you never change the height. If you want the height to wrap, remove `height: 25px;` from `topbar`.

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
#topbartext {font-size: 1em;}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px){
#topbartext{ font-size:25%;}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px){
#topbartext{font-size:50%;} 
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px){
#topbartext{ font-size:50%;}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 960px){
#topbartext{ font-size:70%;}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1280px){
#topbartext{ font-size:100%;}
}
```